# PHP simple function not working

Tags: php, sql, function

I can't make a simple echo.

I have an admin.class.php

```
public static function get_quota() {
  return self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM quota");
}

public static function find_by_sql($sql="") { 
  global $database; 
  $result_set = $database->query($sql); 
  $object_array = array(); 
  while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) { 
    $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row); 
  } 
  return $object_array; 
}
```

And my echo code in index.php

```
<?php
    $admin = User::find_by_id($_SESSION['user_id']);
    $admin_class = new Admin();
    $get_quota = Admin::get_quota();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quota";
    $get_quota = Admin::find_by_sql($sql);
?>
.
.
.
<?php echo $get_quota->daily_a; ?>
```

So my problem is, that the code is not working. I cannot echo my data. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Why would a static function need reference to this/self?

Comment: @Zach Leighton: how would you call a method otherwise?

Comment: You're "getting quota" twice. That aside, have you tried to issue the query by hand ? What did you get ? What do you expect from `find_by_sql()` ? What is the structure of table `quota` ? So many details are missing...

Comment: Static functions exist "before" and "after" the class basically they are functions, not methods. sub add(a,b) { return a + b; } would be a static function, it doesn't depend on the object/class.

Comment: @Zach Leighton: what programming language are you talking about? Static functions are class definition members. And you **have** to either use a class name or `self` to invoke them.

Comment: @zerkms sorry was thinking in a C mindset.. switching between web/compiled can wreak havoc on cognitive ability lol, I retract my earlier comments.

Comment: The quota table's structure:

1 id
2 daily_a
3 weekly_a
4 monthly_a
5 yearly_a

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here:

```
<?php echo $get_quota->daily_a; ?>
```

This line references the `$get_quota` variable and searches for a member field `daily_a`. Try this:

```
<?php echo "Quota is:".var_export($get_quota->daily_a,true); ?>
```

This will show that that is simply an empty variable.

However, also note:

```
$get_quota = Admin::get_quota();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quota";
$get_quota = Admin::find_by_sql($sql);
```

Here you are calling two separate methods from `Admin` and setting the variable `$get_quota` to the result. The second overwrites the first. Therefore the `get_quota()` method doesn't help us here: we need to know what your `find_by_sql()` method returns.

**EDIT (Post new code added to question)**

You can implement logging/echoing within the function you've a problem with:

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql="") { 
  global $database; //Note this is bad practice (1).
  $result_set = $database->query($sql); 
  echo "Result Set: ".var_export($result_set,true)."\n";//This should return something if you're getting something back from the database. Also, remove this for runtime (obviously).

  if (count($result_set) <= 0) { //constraint checking is always good! And cheap!
    error_log("An unexpected number of rows (0) was received from the database for query='".$sql."'.");
  }

  $object_array = array(); 
  while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) { 
    $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row); //Ensure that the instantiate function returns something!
  } 

  echo "Object Array: ".var_export($object_array, true)."\n";//double-check your instantiate function is working
  return $object_array; 
}
```

Based on this code, your problem is likely with the instantiate function; if it's not returning anything, `$object_array` is probably empty. (But not null!).

(1) You should avoid grabbing global variables like this. Instead, instantiate a class that holds and manages your database connection. Then make your `find_by_sql` function non-static and have a member field pointing to your database.

Comment: `var_dump` or `var_export` would be valid as well, but on the event that neither returns it's useful to tack on some hard-coded string just to prove the echo is running.

Comment: `var_dump` is **always** more useful than `echo` - using it you could distinguish between `null`, `false`, `0` and `''`. With `echo` you can only *continue guessing*.

Comment: First of all, you'll see I updated the question. Secondly, the echo is still useful for the reason stated before.

Comment: The find_by_sql() method:
`public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
      $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
   }`

And yes, you are right. Quota is:NULL :(

Comment: @kidi I updated the question and answer. If Quota is actually `null`, and not just empty, you have a stranger problem that will take more thinking.